# python script fails to work when using nohup

Tags: python, python-3.x, centos, python-3.8, nohup

I am trying to execute a python script using the following syntax

```
[root@staging bucket-sync]# nohup python main.py
```

This script runs the following command inside:

```
import os
logging_directory = '/var/log/s3bucket'
os.system(f'mkdir {logging_directory}')
```

but in nohup.out I get the following error:

```
  File "main.py", line 20
    os.system(f'mkdir {logging_directory}')
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "main.py", line 20
    os.system(f'mkdir {logging_directory}')
                                         ^
```

However, when I run the script without nohup, it works perfectly fine.

Is there a relationship  between nohup and python and if so, can it be configured somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hazarding a guess here, but if you specify `python3` when you run this it should work.

You get this error from python 2, since it doesn't understand `f''` strings.